# PHP - Display MySQL data based on user selection on new page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display every job record in my database and when a user clicks on a record, it will go on to display the job description for that record on a new page.

At my current state I've managed to display every job, clicking on them will direct the user to the "showjob.php?id=". My problem is that it isn't displaying information for my job.

**Page with list of jobs: *THIS WORKS***

```
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jobs');
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<a class="job_listing_href" href="showjob.php?id="' . $row['job_id'] . '><div id="job_listing">' . $row['job_title'] . '   ' 
            . $row['cat_job'] . '</div><br/><br/>';
}
```

**Page with individual job information:**

```
    $pkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['job_id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_id='$pkey'";
    foreach ($results as $pdo) {
        echo '<div id="job_listing">' . $row['job_title'] . '   ' . $row['cat_job'] . '</div><div id="job_listing_content">' . $row['job_desc'] . 
        '</div>';
    }
```

It isn't related to my `job_desc` as I can implement it to my previous page and it lists it just fine. My guess is that it's something to do with my `$_GET` but not sure.

Also as a sidenote, I'm aware my website is vulnerable to SQL injection, I'm going to fix it soon :)
Can anyone provide a solution or put me on the right tracks?

Thank you to anyone spending the time helping me!

**UPDATE**

I have took everyone's suggestions - thank you, but my "showjob" page still isn't displaying anything. This is my new code:

```
$pkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_id='$pkey'";
        $results = $pdo->query($sql);
            foreach($results as $row) {
                echo '<div id="job_listing">' . $row['job_title'] . '   ' . $row['cat_job'] . '</div><div id="job_listing_content">' . $row['job_desc'] . 
                '</div>';
                }
```

Comment: you're missing `$results = $pdo->query($sql);` and the `foreach` should loop `$results as $row`

Comment: *Curious:* Are you using `mysql_` ***with*** PDO here and at the same time? and which MySQL API are you using to connect with?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not sure if I understand your question, I'm quite a newb with php but I'm using PDO to connect

Comment: simple: you can't mix MySQL APIs here `mysql_real_escape_string` is a `mysql_` function and you're connecting with PDO. ***No love***. every answers below are wrong so far. Look at my link I left you above. The question may get closed because of it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah I see. do you know an equivalent function I can use for PDO?

Comment: what you're looking to use here, is a PDO prepared statement http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements and get rid of that `mysql_` escape function. Follow the manual and you'll get your answer. Prepare the statement and remember to execute. It's all in the manual ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: They *should* not work together but *can*. You are true, ofc, in that this is an abomination. However, PDO vs mysql_* is not at the very core of this question, so I do not see how this would be a duplicate.

Comment: @DaSourcerer True, I've seen it before. In this instance though, OP is connected via the PDO MySQL API and querying with an `mysql_` function, so that will fail if they haven't also connected using `mysql_connect()`. It's unknown, but I can bet my last dollar they're not ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Debatable. I think `mysql_real_escape_string()` was one of those functions that would silently invoke some black voodoo magic to acquire a valid link descriptor in a last-ditch effort. Can't be bothered to check now, though. Let's agree that everyone will be better of once this is gone, m'kay? ;)

Comment: @DaSourcerer *hehe*, no problemo ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @DaSourcerer I made a slight edit (well, amongst others) in regards to *"the mix"* ;-) I'm not kicking for an upvote here, so don't get me wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_real_escape_string()` while being connected using PDO, so you can't use those together while connecting/querying for the same code.

- Sidenote: You theoretically could with older versions of PHP, but as of PHP 7.0, the `mysql_` API has been removed, so you definitely wouldn't be able to use it here if that were the case.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

> *"This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0."*

What you need to use here is a PDO prepared statement in order to escape the data, which is what you are looking to do here.

```
$pdo = new PDO("...");

if(!empty($_GET['job_id'])){

$pkey = $_GET['job_id'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_id = :jobid");
$statement->execute(array(':jobid' => $pkey));

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // echo $row['field1'].' '.$row['field2']; //etc... taken from an example, sorry.
        echo '<div id="job_listing">' . $row['job_title'] . '   ' . $row['cat_job'] . '</div><div id="job_listing_content">' . $row['job_desc'] . 
    '</div>';
}

}

else{
   echo "GET is empty, check for errors.";
}
```

Also check for errors if you're not already doing so.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

PDO references:

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements
- http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

---

**Footnotes:**

I noticed you're using `href="showjob.php?id` yet you're using the `$_GET['job_id']` array.

- `id` != `job_id`.

That will fail you if that's what you're still using and both of those **need to match.**

Error reporting would have told you about that.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Other notes:

If your server does not support the `mysql_` MySQL API, then error reporting would have thrown you something similar to the following:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()...

Comment: @FirstOne Good. I won't have to give it a bold typeset then ;-) Edit: hey... where'd you go? lol

Answer (score 0):

The results are not showing because you have your variable names mixed up, see below revision:
Change:

```
 $pkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['job_id']);
```

to:

```
 $pkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Update: You are also missing: `$results = $pdo->query($sql);`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the job id parameter as `id`. However, when fetching the id for the specific job, you're retrieving `job_id` out of the `$_GET` superglobal. `$_GET['id']` instead of `$_GET['job_id']`should work.

PS: As Alex pointed out, actually issuing a query via `$results = $pdo->query($sql)` may also help. Followed by iterating over `foreach($results as $row)`. Although there should only ever be one result ...

Answer (score 0):

seems that

```
foreach ($results as $pdo) {
                echo '<div id="job_listing">' . $row['job_title']
```

in foreach your are using $pdo name value, but inside using $row, use the same an tell us.
expect it help